# Differences between wave function and set of orthonormal wave functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, probability, linear-algebra

I'm reading a QM book. It first says for wave function:

> "The state of a physical system (or particle) is completely specified
>   by an entity associated with it called a wave function, Ψ , that in
>   general depends on the spatial coordinates of the system and time. The
>   square modulus of this wave function is the probability density for
>   finding the system with a specified set of values for the spatial and
>   temporal coordinates"

But later it says:

> "At any given instant in time, the wave function Ψ of a particle (or
>   an isolated system) can be expressed as a linear superposition of a
>   complete orthonormal set of wave functions Ψn"

and

> "$a_n = |c_n|^2$ represents the probability that the system will be found in
>   state Ψn"

What?

I'm confused.

We, already, can get probabilities of system from wave function itself. What is that orthonormal wave functions thing?

Comment: Are you asking why we would want to express the wavefunction like that or did you never take a linear algebra class?

Answer (score 2):

The former and the latter are really the same: "$c_n=\psi(x)$".

If you want to measure positions, then possible outcome states are $|x\rangle$, therefore you write
$$
|\psi\rangle = \sum_x|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle:=\sum_x\psi(x)|x\rangle
:=\sum_xc_x|x\rangle
$$
This tells you, the probability to find the particle at position $x$, i.e. to measure it in the state $|x\rangle$ is $|c_x|^2=|\psi(x)|^2$

If you perform another type of measurement, then the set of possible outcomes is described by other states, call them $|\lambda_n\rangle$. Then you write
$$
|\psi\rangle = \sum_n|\lambda_n\rangle\langle\lambda_n|\psi\rangle
:=\sum_n\tilde c_n|\lambda_n\rangle
$$
Therefore the probability to find your system in state $|\lambda_n\rangle$ is $|\tilde c_n|^2$.

Comment: Thanks. But first it says: a wave function of a particle gives the probabilities of its position. But later it says: for every possible position there is a wave function. Isn't that what is says? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: I think in your book they are being imprecise about what they call wave function. In the first part they call the coefficients $\psi(x,t)$ wave function, in the second they call $|\psi(t)\rangle$ wave function. The relation between them is, as written above, that the former are coefficients of the latter for a specific choice of basis. I'd stick to calling $|\psi\rangle$ wave function.

Answer (score 1):

Your book is almost correct. Remember $ \psi $   is the wave function that represents the state of the system and is the solution of the Schrodinger's equation.

Now, the Schrodinger's Equation is a **linear partial differential equation** (PDE) and the solution has several interesting properties: It has **infinitely many particular solutions** and we consider only those which are physically interesting (this is a fancy way of saying that we take those conditions that satisfy the boundary condition). The solutions are also **'orthogonal'** and **'complete'.**

This enables us to write the wave function $ \psi $ as a sum (more precisely, as a **linear combination**) of these orthogonal functions $\psi_{n} $(more precisely, stationary states).

The $ |c_{n}|^2\ 's$ are the coefficients $\psi_{n} $ in of the linear combination mentioned earlier and are interpreted as

> probability that a measurement of the energy would yield the value $ E_{n} $.

Most books interpet it as the *"probability of finding the particle in the nth stationary state $ \psi_{n}$"* but Griffiths insists that it is wrong and gives the above explanation.

I suggest you read Chapter 2 from Griffiths' book. Section 2.1 and 2.2 will answer your question more lucidly.